# Edit plist XML file from Maven?

Tags: xml, maven, xpath, maven-plugin, edit

I have an XML file where I keep relevant default values for my application, such as the server URL. I use Maven to build my application. My goal is to edit the XML and change the server URL depending on the environment I will be using, such as development, test and production environment.

The XML file is of type plist and cannot be changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ServerURL</key>
    <string>https://server_url</string>

    <!-- Other properties goes here -->

</dict>
</plist>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I have found the *xmltask* but no working example on how to something like this. I want something that is really simple to perform a simple task like this. Is there maybe a simple Maven plugin that fixes this? I know XPath and it would be nice to use a simple XPath expression to change the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use profiles and filtering of resources with [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) for this task.

For example, in your XML config file you can specify server URL like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ServerURL</key>
    <string>${server.url}</string>

    <!-- Other properties goes here -->

</dict>
</plist>
```

Meanwhile, in your pom.xml file you should define server.url property

```
<properties>
  <server.url>http://default_url</server.url>
</properties>
```

and one (or several) profiles that will modify its value

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>custom</id>
    <properties>
      <server.url>http://custom_url</server.url>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Sorry but this solution does not seems to be usable, since my XML format is fixed. I have edited my question to be a little bit specific. But it was a good answer provided my little vague question :)

Comment: Format can be fixed, but content should be flexible =) Replace <string> element value into ${server.url}. When you copy resources, use filtering to substitute the property with actual value. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html article for reference.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you. Given the format is plist and the tag must be _<string>_, I cannot see how this solution would work for me.

Comment: Maven will automatically substitute ${server.url} property into correct value based on the profile that is used. For example, if you build your project with 'mvn package', Maven will use default value of ${server.url} property (http://default_url in case of mine configuration). If you build your project with 'mvn package -P custom', then Maven will substitute ${server.url} property reference into its value in custom profile (http://custom_url).

Comment: Thanks @Nico for editing the example to follow the provided sample from the question.